# svg как плавно отрисовать "Галочку"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Есть svg (галочка), как правильно плавно отрисовать её?

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="725.3px" height="725.301px" viewBox="0 0 725.3 725.301" style="enable-background:new 0 0 725.3 725.301;" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
    <path d="M299.188,725.301c-0.202,0-2.158-0.033-2.36-0.033c-20.094-1.248-36.311-10.216-46.257-24.646L66.957,433.596
                c-18.341-26.702-11.564-63.317,15.071-81.658c25.995-17.835,63.924-10.62,81.658,15.104l127.444,185.333L556.571,32.013
                C571,3.76,607.987-8.31,636.27

3,6.12c14.094,7.181,24.579,19.454,29.468,34.524c4.889,15.07,3.607,31.119-3.607,45.212
            l-309.709,607.28c-0.708,1.382-3.169,4.687-4.214,5.799c-0.405,0.641-1.618,2.091-2.124,2.697
            c-2.63,3.438-6.035,7.586-10.553,11.126c-1.045,1.079-2.293,2.226-3.169,2.832c-3.203,2.158-6.103,3.169-7.822,3.776
            c-4.214,1.922-6.406,2.899-8.833,3.573C310.549,724.525,305.054,725.301,299.188,725.301z M115.304,375.303
            c-5.057,0-9.946,1.517-14.16,4.416c-11.329,7.788-14.194,23.398-6.373,34.761l183.58,266.958
            c5.563,8.092,14.261,9.811,18.948,10.114h1.888c2.562,0,4.788-0.304,7.013-0.978c0.101-0.034,3.304-1.518,3.405-1.551
            c0.876-0.438,2.023-0.877,3.203-1.315c0.303-0.27,0.607-0.539,0.843-0.708c2.326-1.72,3.979-3.742,5.361-5.597
            c2.292-2.967,3.338-4.214,4.417-5.395l308.63-605.493c3.102-6.103,3.642-13.014,1.551-19.487
            c-2.09-6.474-6.608-11.767-12.711-14.869c-12.44-6.338-28.118-1.011-34.355,11.193L308.291,592.901
            c-2.697,5.293-7.99,8.766-13.924,9.17c-6.204,0.337-11.632-2.394-15.003-7.282l-143.492-208.63
            C131.251,379.382,123.531,375.303,115.304,375.303z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вариант плавной прорисовки:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="725.3px" height="725.301px" viewBox="0 0 725.3 725.301" style="enable-background:new 0 0 725.3 725.301;" xml:space="preserve">
    <g>
        <style>
            .st0{ fill: none; stroke: #000000; stroke-width: 5; stroke-miterlimit: 5; }
            .st0 {
                stroke-dasharray: 1000;
                stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
                animation: dash 7s linear forwards;
            }

            @keyframes dash {
                from{
                    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
                }
                to {
                  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
                }
            }
            
        </style>
        
        
        <path class="st0" d="m 38.415077,45.934734 c 11.069026,16.389914 11.069026,16.389914 11.069026,16.389914 6.037651,-38.63337 6.037651,-38.63337 6.037651,-38.63337" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Шаблон галочки взял из ответа `Stargazer` .

Вот второй вариант `animate fill`:

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="725.3px" height="725.301px" viewBox="0 0 725.3 725.301" style="enable-background:new 0 0 725.3 725.301;" xml:space="preserve">
  <g>
      <style>
            
            @keyframes fill {
              0% {
                  fill: white;
              }
              100% {
                  fill: black;
              }
          }

          .st0 {
              fill: black;
              animation-name: fill;
              animation-duration: 4s;
              animation-iteration-count: forwards;
          }
            
            
        </style>
      
      
    <path class='st0' d="M299.188,725.301c-0.202,0-2.158-0.033-2.36-0.033c-20.094-1.248-36.311-10.216-46.257-24.646L66.957,433.596
                c-18.341-26.702-11.564-63.317,15.071-81.658c25.995-17.835,63.924-10.62,81.658,15.104l127.444,185.333L556.571,32.013
                C571,3.76,607.987-8.31,636.27

3,6.12c14.094,7.181,24.579,19.454,29.468,34.524c4.889,15.07,3.607,31.119-3.607,45.212
            l-309.709,607.28c-0.708,1.382-3.169,4.687-4.214,5.799c-0.405,0.641-1.618,2.091-2.124,2.697
            c-2.63,3.438-6.035,7.586-10.553,11.126c-1.045,1.079-2.293,2.226-3.169,2.832c-3.203,2.158-6.103,3.169-7.822,3.776
            c-4.214,1.922-6.406,2.899-8.833,3.573C310.549,724.525,305.054,725.301,299.188,725.301z M115.304,375.303
            c-5.057,0-9.946,1.517-14.16,4.416c-11.329,7.788-14.194,23.398-6.373,34.761l183.58,266.958
            c5.563,8.092,14.261,9.811,18.948,10.114h1.888c2.562,0,4.788-0.304,7.013-0.978c0.101-0.034,3.304-1.518,3.405-1.551
            c0.876-0.438,2.023-0.877,3.203-1.315c0.303-0.27,0.607-0.539,0.843-0.708c2.326-1.72,3.979-3.742,5.361-5.597
            c2.292-2.967,3.338-4.214,4.417-5.395l308.63-605.493c3.102-6.103,3.642-13.014,1.551-19.487
            c-2.09-6.474-6.608-11.767-12.711-14.869c-12.44-6.338-28.118-1.011-34.355,11.193L308.291,592.901
            c-2.697,5.293-7.99,8.766-13.924,9.17c-6.204,0.337-11.632-2.394-15.003-7.282l-143.492-208.63
            C131.251,379.382,123.531,375.303,115.304,375.303z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Совместил две анимации, - анимация линии галочки и анимация заполнения цветом самой галочки.

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 width="94" height="94" viewBox="0 0 47 47"  >
 <title>animation icon -OK-</title> 
       <circle fill="#4CAF50" cx="24" cy="24" r="21"/>
         <path class="path" fill= "none" stroke ="#CCFF90" stroke-width ="1.5" stroke-dasharray= "70.2" stroke-dashoffset="70.2" 
   d="M 34.6 14.6  L 21 28.2 L 15.4 22.6 L 12.6 25.4 L 21 33.8 L 37.4 17.4z">
   <animate id="p1" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="0.2s" values="70.2;0" dur="3s" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" calcMode="paced" restart="whenNotActive"/> 
   <animate id="f1" attributeName="fill" begin = "p1.end" values="#4CAF50; #CCFF90"  dur="2s" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" /> 
 </path> 
</svg>
```

Анимация рисования линии реализуется с помощью - `attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"`

Длина контура галочки - `70.2px`
Поэтому выбираем значения анимации с 72.2 до нуля - `values="70.2;0"`

По окончанию рисования линии `begin = "p1.end"` начинается вторая анимация - заполнение цветом:

```
<animate id="f1" attributeName="fill" begin = "p1.end" values="#4CAF50; #CCFF90"
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда нужен такой простой элемент - самое правильное нарисовать его самому:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 25 25" width="25" height="25">
    <path d="M6 18 L10 23 L20 5" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, автор хочет анимацию появления галочки, типо заливки или что-то в этом роде